# Things get wrong when appending a list to a list in python

Tags: python, list

I am programming a simple software for practicing.

```
def check(num, lst):
    for i in lst:
        if num == i:
            return False
    else:
       lst.append(num)
       return True

timelst = []
for i1 in range(1,7):
    usednum = [i1]

    for i2 in range(1,7):
        if not check(i2, usednum):
            continue

        for i3 in range(1,7):
            if not check(i3, usednum):
                continue

            for i4 in range(1,7):
                if not check(i4, usednum):
                    continue

                for i5 in range(1,7):
                    if not check(i5, usednum):
                        continue

                    for i6 in range(1,7):
                        if not check(i6, usednum):
                            continue
                        else:

                            print(usednum)   #print the appending list before actual appending
                            timelst.append(usednum)
                            usednum.pop()
                            break

                    usednum.pop()
```

When running this, this is what I want the timelst to be like:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5],
 [2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 [2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 5],
 ...
]
```

However this is what I actually get:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 [2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 [2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 ...
]
```

I am really confused about this and got stuck for a long time. I tried printing the 'usednum' list before appending it, and it returns perfectly what I want.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5]
[2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 5]
#printed lists while running the program
```

But the same problem still occurs everytime when I check the timelst after executing the program.

I used python 3.7 with spyder.  There should not be a problem with my compiler, as I have tried running this on ipython and I still got the same result.

Can anyone please help me solving this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Multiple nested loops like this is generally considered bad programming practice, especially when the loops do the same thing. It's not entirely clear to me what you want the output to be ... what is the intention of this code?

Comment: Basically I want to append every possible combinations of the numbers under six to a list, such as 123456 123465 123546 123564 ... 654312 654321, and this is the most efficient way I can think to achieve this, rather than append all possible lists and remove the ones with repeating numbers. The program is not totally finished, it should work, ideally and maybe logically, if I add timelst.pop() at the end of every loop after the previous loop finishes. I did try it, but it gave me a much worse result like [[1], [1], [1], ...., [6], [6], [6]]. I realise maybe they are caused by the same problem.

Comment: check the indentation of your `check` function.

Comment: Sorry that was just a silly mistake when I was transferring my code to my post. It was correct in my compiler and that did not cause any problem, and the indentation of function has been corrected in my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved! I should have realised earlier that there had been an issue about the shallow and deep copy of the list I have appended. I have add

```
usednum = copy.deepcopy(usednum)
```

to the final loop, so it now looks like

```
for i6 in range(1, 7):
    if not check(i6, usednum):
        continue
    else:
        timelst.append(usednum)
        usednum = copy.deepcopy(usednum) #the new copy of the appended list, so now there's nothing to do with the appended one.
        print('i6',usednum.pop())
        break

    usednum.pop()
```

which can work properly now

Answer (score 0):

You can make your life a lot easier by using the [itertools.permutations()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.permutations) function call:

```
import itertools

mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for item in itertools.permutations(mylist):
    # Do something with item, which is a permutation of 'mylist'
    print(item)
```

Note, however, that this results in a big (`6!` ... that is six-factorial) list of results. If you only want combinations, take a look at [itertools.combinations()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.combinations) instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't realise I could find a toolkit to reach my purpose. However, at this stage, I am still wondering what makes my program not work properly, as the 'usednum' list printed in the previous step is [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5], but as it is appended to the 'timelst', it becomes [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].